# how to rewrite url from rewrite.php to form

Tags: php, .htaccess

HI iam using this code  for url rewriting but getting output object not found pls any  one  help me to getting the output like rewrite.php replace to form.

Untitled Document

```
 <body>
 </body>
 <form method="post" action="rewrite/">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Form</legend>

 <input type="name" />
 <input type="name" />
 <input type="name" />
 <input type="name" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" />


 </fieldset>
  </form>
  </html>
  <!----this is my index file--->


   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
     </head>

     Hello this is htaccess page !!!!!

     <body>
     </body>
     </html>  
    <! this htacess code iam using-->
     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
       # Turn mod_rewrite on
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteRule ^form/([0-9]+)/?$ /rewrite.php?vp=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/form/([0-9]+)$ /rewrite.php?id=$1
```

Comment: @user3377853 i would suggest you that you should maintain a .htaccess file for url rewriting

Comment: still getting object not found

Comment: the url is change to form but getting a page object not found

Comment: actuallly i want to rewrite the page name to name like rewrite.php to avnish  on the url when i open tha page rewrite .php so i want to see my name not page name  if   you have any othere option pls let me know